# Which is the best crystal report version for Vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Now i'm using Crystal report 13.0.0.99. Is better to use another version like 13.0.16.1954? Did the newer version fix bugs or something?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the release notes. http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 I usually just stick with what is working, unless your installation is public facing, and vulnerable or if you have a specific problem.